# How would I say "Time it takes to fall after casting" as short as possible?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

As said in the title. The "Time it takes to fall after casting" is only for a title and should not show a time.

Comment: Could it be the case that you do not want the word "time" to figure in this phrase?

Comment: Also, what is the _it_ that is falling?

Comment: Your questions should be clear. In this case we do not know what you are talking about: casting as in an actor chosen for a role; throwing a stone; pouring molten metal; casting around for a solution to a problem? An example would  help. If you refer to the fall of a thrown (cast) stone, do you refer only to the falling part of its trajectory (if the trajectory has a falling part)  or do you refer to the whole trajectory, which may include an upward part.

Comment: Yes, i refer to something like throwing a stone, and the 'time' is how long it takes to begin falling.

Comment: I also refer to the whole stone.

Comment: @luvenbraven The whole stone or the whole trajectory.